# How to factor a polynomial with NumPy and print it nicely?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a NumPy script that can calculate the factors of a polynomial and verify it as well. I have used [this](https://sjmiller8182.github.io/posts/2020/03/polynomials_in_numpy/#polynomial_roots_by_factor) guide as a skeleton for my code.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfromroots, polyval, polyroots, Polynomial, polymul

p = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

print(Polynomial(p))

roots = polyroots(p)

print("\nroots: ")
print(roots)

factors = np.empty([len(roots), 2])
for i in range(0, len(roots)):
    factors[i] = np.real(polyfromroots([roots[i]]))
    
print("\nfactors:")
print(factors)

original = np.array([1])

for i in range(0, len(factors)):
    original = np.real(polymul(original, factors[i]))
    
print("\noriginal:")
print(original.astype(int))
```

I am using Mathematica to verify my result

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+++x%C2%B2+%2B+x%C2%B3+%2B+x%E2%81%B4+%2B+x%E2%81%B5+%2B+x%E2%81%B6+%2B+x%E2%81%B7+%2B+x%E2%81%B8+%2B+x%E2%81%B9+%2B+x%C2%B9%E2%81%B0+%2B+x%C2%B9%C2%B9+%2B+x%C2%B9%C2%B2+%2B+x%C2%B9%C2%B3+%2B+x%C2%B9%E2%81%B5+%2B+x%C2%B9%E2%81%B7+%2B+x%C2%B9%E2%81%B9

But it doesn't comply with my Python output

```
0.0 + 0.0·x¹ + 1.0·x² + 1.0·x³ + 0.0·x⁴ + 1.0·x⁵ + 0.0·x⁶ + 0.0·x⁷ +
1.0·x⁸ + 1.0·x⁹ + 0.0·x¹⁰ + 1.0·x¹¹ + 0.0·x¹² + 1.0·x¹³ + 0.0·x¹⁴ +
1.0·x¹⁵ + 0.0·x¹⁶ + 1.0·x¹⁷ + 0.0·x¹⁸ + 1.0·x¹⁹

roots: 
[-8.47263459e-01-0.34321226j -8.47263459e-01+0.34321226j
 -8.37756399e-01-0.65620643j -8.37756399e-01+0.65620643j
 -6.73597516e-01+0.j         -4.87413694e-01-1.00896551j
 -4.87413694e-01+1.00896551j  0.00000000e+00+0.j
  0.00000000e+00+0.j          1.38777878e-16-1.j
  1.38777878e-16+1.j          1.36617682e-01-1.00029444j
  1.36617682e-01+1.00029444j  5.95058017e-01-0.90873967j
  5.95058017e-01+0.90873967j  8.27603066e-01-0.59053628j
  8.27603066e-01+0.59053628j  9.49953546e-01-0.3204439j
  9.49953546e-01+0.3204439j ]

factors:
[[ 8.47263459e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.47263459e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.37756399e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 8.37756399e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 6.73597516e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 4.87413694e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 4.87413694e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]
 [-0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.38777878e-16  1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.38777878e-16  1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.36617682e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.36617682e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-5.95058017e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-5.95058017e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-8.27603066e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-8.27603066e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-9.49953546e-01  1.00000000e+00]
 [-9.49953546e-01  1.00000000e+00]]

original:
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0 -5  0  6  0 -3  0  1]
```

Comment: `polyroots` returns estimates of the root eigenvectors, not the actual roots: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots.html

Comment: So I guess it works the small example in the guide, but yields too large of an error for polynomials of a degree higher than two?